# RewriteCond in .htaccess to search robots.txt and sitemap.xml in domain subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to write a rewriterule to search for robots.txt and sitemap.xml files in a subfolder that match the domain name with or without the www. Let’s take an example:

- I have domains aaa.com, bbb.com and ccc.com
- They are all installed in the same root folder %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}
- They can be accessed with or without the www.

If someone is trying to access the http://aaa.com/robots.txt file, I would like to perform the following:

If the files requested is robots.txt {

- If there is a file that matches a subfolder %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/aaa.com/robots.txt (give this file and stop) *1
- ElseIf there is a file that matches a subfolder
  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/www.aaa.com/robots.txt (give this file and stop) *2
- Else give the file %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/robots.txt *3

}

I don’t want to hardcode the domain names; I tried to take them from the request but I wasn’t able to check the conditions *2 and *3:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/robots.txt$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /www\.%{HTTP_HOST}/robots\.txt [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitemap.xml$
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ /www\.%{HTTP_HOST}/sitemap\.xml [L]
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
# prevent any kind of looping:
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# first check host/robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)$ /%2/$1 [L]

# then check www.host/robots.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/www.%2/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)$ /www.%2/$1 [L]

# finally, do nothing and allow the "/robots.txt" request to resolve itself
```

Comment: Hello, can you tell me what is the looping prevention in your answer and how does it work?

Comment: @momcho The `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200` line checks if there was an internal redirect (status would = 200 if there was one, otherwise that env variable is blank). If so, pass the request URI through and do nothing. That ends all rewriting on the spot.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! The configuration works fine. The only thing I didn't understand is why it is possible to have an internal redirect? Can you give an example? I thought to put the following `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)$` on the top of each RewriteCond block to be sure of the request on robots.txt or sitemap.xml...

Comment: @momcho it's because the rewrite engine loops until there is nothing to do.